# What's the complexity of the problem of optimally distribute n balls in m boxes?

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization

Assuming that there is a function $f(x)$ (non linear, non convex) where $x$ is the vector $[n_1,n_2,\dots n_m]$ where $n_i$ is the number of balls in the box $i \in \{1,\dots m\}$, and $\sum \limits_i^m n_i = n$.

What is the complexity of the problem of finding the distribution of balls that maximize $f(x)$?
Also what's a good algorithm for solving this kind of problems?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  1. What do you know about $f$?  The answer will depend a lot on the properties of $f$.  If you know nothing, then the complexity could be very bad.  If you want good answers, it's in your interests to tell us as much as possible as you know about the properties of $f$.  Is it differentiable?  Monotonic?     2. How is $f$ presented?  What form is it provided in?  Is $f$ part of the input, or is it fixed?  If it's fixed, what are the inputs?  When you say "complexity", as a function of what parameter?  Please edit the question to provide this information.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.

Comment: If $f$ is zero everywhere except for one particular configuration of balls and you have to treat $f$ as a black box, then you have to try all configurations.

Comment: You haven't even defined how you apply $f$ either. Is it $\sum_{i=1}^m f(n_i)?$, hardly obvious.